# to find position of identified patterns in protein sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to write a code to find patterns in a protein sequence and then find the positions (start and end) for the identified pattern. For the identified pattern, when i search for the index using .index(), i do not get the correct start position if multiple patterns are there. But here i want the start and end position for the identified patterns. 
I am looking for an easy and quick way rather doing BLAST.

```
import re
from io import StringIO

from Bio import SeqIO

sequence = StringIO(""">seq
FWSTQALLPTTLLGASP
""")

for seqs in SeqIO.parse(sequence, "fasta"):
    # to find pattern
    p = re.compile("L*")
    seqstr = str(seqs.seq)
    patternA = p.findall(seqstr)
    print(patternA)
    for t in patternA:
        print(seqstr.index(t))
```

Expected result:
`7 LL 8`
`12 LL 13`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As most developers does not have knowledge in identifying patterns in protein sequences, could you please add more context to your question? Moreover the code you have provided does not work properly, a sequence as to be constructed via the Bio.Seq(sequence) constructor and the SeqIO.parse() generator does not yield anything.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion.It was my mistake as i modified it for posting here and i missed to change it in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

[`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) is what you probably want to use as it will give you a [`match object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) which have the `start` and `end` coordinates of the match; these can be used for slicing the substring from the original string.

```py
import re
from io import StringIO

from Bio import SeqIO

sequence = StringIO(
    """>seq
FWSTQALLPTTLLGASPL
"""
)

for seqs in SeqIO.parse(sequence, "fasta"):
    # to find pattern
    p = re.compile("L*")
    seqstr = str(seqs.seq)
    matches = p.finditer(seqstr)

    for m in matches:
        if m.group():
            start, end = m.span()
            print(
                "{start} {match} {end}".format(start=start, match=m.group(), end=end)
            )
```

Which outputs:

```
6 LL 8
11 LL 13
```

---

A note on strings in python, they are zero based, which means the first character is numbered `0`. It is worth reading the [tutorial on strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). Breifly, using your sequence:

```
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
           | F | W | S | T | Q | A | L | L | P | T | T | L | L | G | A | S | P |
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
slice pos: 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
index pos:   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16

# So using the output you can see:
>>> seq[6:8]
'LL'
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alex and for the nice explanation. You saved my day!